# Why is this value constructor not hidden?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Refer to https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors and module code:

```
module Resistor (
         Resistor,       -- abstract, hiding constructors
         metalResistor,  -- only way to build a metal resistor
       ) where

 ...
```

When I try this in ghci, I am able to call both `metalResistor` and `Metal`. Metal was supposed to be hidden. 
What should I do to properly hide the `Resistor` value constructor?

Comment: That's because GHCi ignores the list of exports and exports everything from the module.

Comment: **Do not trust GHCi**. It behaves differently from GHC. If you find something odd when using GHCi try to past the code into a file and compile it.